# spark sort & filter

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm looking for an option in pyspark to do sort & filter together,
and take just x rows according column value.
for example

My df:

```
keys   |   values
-----------------
 a     |  4
 b     |  5
 c     |  3
 d     |  1
 e     |  2
```

```
def sort_and_filter_based_on_column(df, column, num_of_rows)
    #here I do logic
```

expected output:

```
sort_and_filter_based_on_column(df, "values", 3).show()
>>
keys   |   values
-----------------
 c     |  3
 d     |  1
 e     |  2

sort_and_filter_based_on_column(df, "values", 2).show()
>>
keys   |   values
-----------------
 d     |  1
 e     |  2

sort_and_filter_based_on_column(df, "values", 5).show()
>>
keys   |   values
-----------------
 a     |  4
 b     |  5
 c     |  3
 d     |  1
 e     |  2
```

obviously, I want to do it most efficient that I can.

Comment: How are you sorting and filtering exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform this task using

```py
sorted_and_limit_df = df.orderBy('values').limit(num_of_rows)
sorted_and_limit_df.show()
```